# Plain and simple 2D rotation in Krita?

Tags: krita, rotate

I just gave Krita a go after a few major versions of not using it, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do a SIMPLE, NORMAL, kindergarten level 2D rotation of a layer. When I use the Rotate option of the transform tool, move the pivot to the desired position, and try *dragging something* to specify the rotation angle in **analog** manner, two possible things happen, neither of which is desirable:

- the layer is moved instead of rotated, or
- the layer is rotated **every which freaking way in 3D**, **except** for the simple rotation in 2D about the z-oriented axis going through the pivot

HOW DO I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pasted as a new image to Krita. The transformation tool is activated and the pivot point is moved near the P in the title:

[image]

The image has become temporarily partially transparent, which can be very handy if there's a layer below.

In the next screenshot it's dragged to different angle. The mouse cursor must be outside the rotated area. Otherwise the layer is moved.

[image]

The rotated layer is cropped to the document size and the transparency is gone after another tool is selected:

[image]

A good thing to know: Nothing is deleted, everything is still there and can be rotated or moved back to the visible area.

Comment: Thanks! "The mouse cursor must be outside the rotated area" was the missing bit of completely unguessable UI. Seriously, whose ever idea was it that in order to interact with something in the SINGLE way that the ACTIVE TOOL is supposed to interact with things, you need NOT to GRAB THE THING, but to WAVE YOUR HAND AT CERTAIN DISTANCE FROM THE THING? Was the UI designer from a race of naturally telekinetic beings? Is that how they would turn (i.e. rotate) a doorknob?

Comment: Maybe he has used Photoshop. It works in the same way except to activate rotation one must at first drag the rotation handle. After it every point outside the layer area works. Photoshop's approach has a little redundancy. BTW there are many real world things moved by hand without touching. Some persons who do it: Orchestra conductor, traffic police, Theremin player and an infantry squad leading corporal in a combat situation.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski it is unfortunately common to see people who have wild ideas how rotation works and thus you get very wild design ideas around it.